# How to save an image using toyplot (failed example)

Tags: google-colaboratory

In Google's colab jupyter notebook I have a canvas object which displays nicely on the scree. Now I want to save it on the disk as a figure using toyplot:

```
import toyplot.pdf
toyplot.pdf.render(canvas, "fig.pdf")
```

Upon execution the code runs quitely and returns no error.
However, no file is saved nor a dialog is shown.
Using Chrome on Ubuntu.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It works for me. Unless you've changed the default, the file gets written here `/content/fig.pdf`.

Comment: @AndrewChisholm, well I was not able to identify where the defaults could have been possibly changed, but using the full path `/content/fig.pdf` actually solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Click on the `Files` icon at the left to show the file system. By default, you start at `/content'.

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewChisholm. I'm indeed at `content`. However, I still need to supply the full path `/content/fig.pdf` --- and likewise for other functions that access the file system.  Not a big deal, though. I can dig into it eventually to find out.